# A different merge

Tags: pandas, group-by, merge, data-science

So I have two tables and thoses are the samples:

### df1:

| Element | Range | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ae_aag2/0013F | 5-2500 | Chuviridae |
| Ae_aag2/0014F | 300-2100 | Flaviviridae |

### df2:

| Element | Range | Family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0012F | 30-720 | Chuviridae |
| 0013F | 23-1200 | Chuviridae |
| 0013F | 1300-2610 | Xinmoviridae |

And I need to join the tables in the following logic:

| Element_df1 | Element_df2 | Family_df1 | Family_df2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ae_aag2/0013F | "0013F:23-1200,0013F:1300-2610" | Chuviridae | "Chuviridae,Xinmoviridae" |

I need the common rows in the two dataframes of the column (Element) in one line, saving the element of the first and second and also the family of the first and second. If the 3 elements are common, in the two df, it should join the 3 in one single line.

I tried using the `merge` in pandas, but it gets me two lines, not one as I needed:
[image]

I searched and didn't find how make exceptions on how to merge the two dataframe. I tried using `groupby` afterwards but kind make worst :(

Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge on working with pandas. Please be kind I'm new at the subject.

Comment: The logic is not fully clear, also the format in your image is different

Comment: Sorry, but still unclear to me, why is 13F matched with 14F? is the range playing any role?

Comment: @mozway my bad there was a mistake in the samples. my sincere apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1.drop(columns='Range').merge(
    df2.assign(group=lambda d: d['Element'],
               Element=lambda d: d['Element']+':'+d['Range'])
       .groupby('group')[['Element', 'Family']].agg(','.join),
    left_on=df1['Element'].str.extract('/(.*)$', expand=False),
    right_index=True, suffixes=('_df1', '_df2')  
)#.drop(columns='key_0') # uncomment to remove the key
```

Output:

```
   key_0    Element_df1  Family_df1                    Element_df2               Family_df2
0  0013F  Ae_aag2/0013F  Chuviridae  0013F:23-1200,0013F:1300-2610  Chuviridae,Xinmoviridae
```

Comment: There's is a form that can make the "key_0" not appear?

Comment: Add `.drop(columns='key_0')`

Comment: Another question, if is not a problem. There's a way that can only join the elements in two conditionals:
Have the same Element name and overlap in the range?

Comment: Overlap in the range is tricky, maybe this should be a separate question?

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit nervous with this problem, was trying to solve for 3 weeks and was afraid to post a question here. If I had the money would pay you a coffee @mozway.

Comment: If you ask another question for the ranges, please let me know, I'll have a look (maybe not immediately, I'm busy IRL)